# Can you help me see a contradiction in this fake proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Can you please help me see a contradiction in this argument used in answering the problem below:

The problem:

If $(a-b^3)b>0$ then

1)
$\sqrt[3]{a + \frac {9b^3+a}{3b}*\sqrt {\frac {a - b^3}{3b}}}$ + $\sqrt[3]{a - \frac {9b^3+a}{3b}*\sqrt {\frac {a - b^3}{3b}}}$ is a rational.

Argument:

It is known that: If $a + \sqrt[3]{b} = c + \sqrt[3]{d}$ then either $a=c$ or b and d are cubes of rational numbers.

Hence

let 1. = k

Then

$\sqrt[3]{a + \frac {9b^3+a}{3b}*\sqrt {\frac {a - b^3}{3b}}}$ = k -$\sqrt[3]{a - \frac {9b^3+a}{3b}*\sqrt {\frac {a - b^3}{3b}}}$

Since k does not equal 0

$a + \frac {9b^3+a}{3b}*\sqrt {\frac {a - b^3}{3b}}$ is a cube of a rational and hence k is rational.

Comment: Your "known" fact requires some specification.  Surely you meant to require that $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Q$, right?  But in your application of the known fact, you don't know that $k\in \mathbb Q$ at the start.

Comment: @lulu but known fact could apply to reals as well, no?

Comment: In principle, but that generalization is obviously false.  $\sqrt[3] 2+\sqrt[3] 3=\sqrt[3] 3+\sqrt[3] 2$ for instance.